# Symbol less, more with arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

In my last program I misprinted `while (A[0] < n)` with `while(A < [n])`. I don't understand how...

But everything worked correctly!

Now I noticed that and here is question. What do symbols of comparing actually compare?

Quite searching does not give anything because it is not intended to compare arrays just with `<`, I think...

```
A = []

A.append(3)
A.append(2)
A.append(1)

print A
print (A < [2,2,3])
```

gives

```
[3, 2, 1]
False
```

It seems that it really compares `A[0]` with `n`. But may be, I am wrong and here I can find some interesting iteractions?

Sorry, if duplicate, I tried to find smth similar

Comment: Those are lists, Python compares them element-wise, as with other sequences like strings. The first non-equal element determines which is "bigger".

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh. wow. It is true. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you compare two lists, they are compared element by element. The first non-equal element determines the result.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1] > [2]
False

[1, 1, 1, 1] > [0, 2]
True
```